# How to test for sys.stdin ESC in Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make this code also return true if ESC is pressed?

```
   if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
```

Comment: Have you put the terminal into non-buffered mode?

Comment: Or, in other words perhaps, is it only Esc for which your expression does not return true, or is the same also true for most other keys except Enter?

Answer (score 0):

That's a little short on context. `select` is used here to report if there is anything available to read. To find out what, you need to read it. But that's not the same as something being pressed, meaning still held down. For that sort of thing you'll want an interface like [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed). The default behaviour in Unix-like systems is otherwise that the terminal layer processes an entire line - including things like erasing characters with backspace - before handing it off to your program. Any finer detail than that requires using uncooked modes, for instance with [`curses.cbreak()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.cbreak) or [`curses.raw()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.raw). That restores the concept of keypresses, but still won't report whether keys are held. However, the keys themselves are encoded (many use terminal escape sequences, making escape itself the worst one to decode) so you need to use getch or getkey to identify them.